# Other databases deleted after restoring incremental MySQL Enterprise Backup

Tags: mysql, backup, restore

I am trying to restore some databases, which were backed up with MySQL Enterprise Backup (MEB).

The backup uses both full compressed backups and incremental backups.

There is no problem if I restore the full compressed backup, but when I restore the incremental backups, it deletes any other table in the server.

This is the commands to generate the backups:

```
mysqlbackup --login-path=usrbackup --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --compress
    --backup-dir=/backups/mydb-full --backup-image=/backups/mydb-full/full-mydb.mbi
    --include-tables=^mydb\. --exclude-tables=\.temp.+
    backup-to-image

mysqlbackup --login-path=usrbackup --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --incremental
    --incremental-base=dir:/backups/mydb-full
    --backup-dir=/backups/mydb-inc01 --backup-image=/backups/mydb-inc01/inc-mydb.mbi
    --include-tables=^mydb\. --exclude-tables=\.temp.+
    backup-to-image

mysqlbackup --login-path=usrbackup --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --incremental
    --incremental-base=dir:/backups/mydb-inc01
    --backup-dir=/backups/mydb-inc02 --backup-image=/backups/mydb-inc02/inc-mydb.mbi
    --include-tables=^mydb\. --exclude-tables=\.temp.+
    backup-to-image
```

And these are the commands to restore the backups

```
mysqlbackup --login-path=usrbackup --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --uncompress
    --backup-dir=/backups/mydb-full --backup-image=full-mydb.mbi
    copy-back-and-apply-log

mysqlbackup --login-path=usrbackup --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --incremental
    --backup-dir=/backups/mydb-inc01 --backup-image=inc-mydb.mbi
    copy-back-and-apply-log

mysqlbackup --login-path=usrbackup --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --incremental 
    --backup-dir=/backups/mydb-inc02 --backup-image=inc-mydb.mbi
    copy-back-and-apply-log
```

When it deletes any other databases, this includes `mysql`, and `information_schema`, rendering the server completely unusable.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: That's worth a Serious error to bugs.mysql.com